# Read all csv files in directory

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have CSV files in directory and I want to open each one of them and read the first column. Here is my code:

```
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","/Users/user/My Documents/test/")
 for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
           f = open(file, 'r')
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           for row in reader:
                print(row[0])
```

When I run it , I got an error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory : 'file1.csv'
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to solve it:

```
 directory = os.listdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
 os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
 for files in directory:
           with open(files, 'r')as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for row in reader:
                print(row[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because `os.walk` walks recursively through all sub-directories too. So your code should shouldn't assume all files lie in the current directory.

```
directory = os.path.join("c:\\","/Users/user/My Documents/test/")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       f = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r') # I have considered root path too
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for row in reader:
            print(row[0])
```